# Show that Random Graphs Typically Have Diameter 2 (Probabilistic Method)

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs

Show that random graphs typically have diameter 2. That is, the probability that $G_p$, the graph with p vertices, has diameter 2 converges to 1 as $p \rightarrow \infty$.

Hint:
Find the probability that two given vertices have minimal distance > 2 in $G_p$; find the average number of such pairs in $G_p$; make a conclusion.

I could solve this problem if I knew the probability that 2 vertices have distance > 2 in $G_p$, but I don't see how to compute this. Could someone provide me with a nudge in the right direction to finding this probability, so that I can complete the proof?

Comment: What exactly is the distribution of $G_p$?

Comment: $G_p$ is a graph with p vertices and 1/2 chance that an edge exists between any 2 vertices. But i'm still unsure how to proceed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Distance between $w$ and $v$ is $>2$" can be rewritten as "$v$ and $w$ are not neighbors, and they also share no neighbors." Can you further write this event in terms of edges and compute the probability?

> $$P(\text{$v$ and $w$ not neighbors}) \cdot [1 - P(\text{$u$ is a neighbor of both $v$ and $w$})]^{p-2} = (1/2) \cdot (3/4)^{p-2}$$

Then,

> $$E[\text{number of pairs with distance $> 2$}] = \frac{p(p-1)}{2} P(\text{$w$ and $v$ have distance $>2$}) = \frac{p(p-1)}{2}\frac{1}{2} (\frac{3}{4})^{p-2}$$

Comment: So I got the correct expression for the probability of $d > 2$ and then i found the probability of $d=2$ to be $1/2 * (1 - 1/2 (3/4) ^{p-2})$ which is nonzero as $p \rightarrow \infty$. Does this also prove what I'm trying to prove? I'm confused on whether I should attack the end of the proof with expected values or with aiming for nonzero probabilities.

Comment: @rjm27trekkie Use Markov's inequality on the number of pairs with distance $>2$ to show that the probability of "diameter of $G_p$ is $>2$" tends to zero.

Comment: Implicit in this write-up is that in the probability model mentioned by the OP, a graph $G$ is picked according to the uniform distribution of the graphs on $p$ vertices which implies (not a priori obvious) that the probability that an edge exists between two vertices is $\frac{1}{2}$ (and that the probability that a pair of vertices form an edge is independent of whether or not any other pair of vertices form an edge). The diameter is almost surely no more than 2 even if $\frac{1}{2}$ were replaced with something much smaller i.e., $\sqrt{n}^{-1}\log^2 n$; $n$ the number of vtcs